# Mass Insertion of Users/Passwords into ASP.Identity Users and Memberships Tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'd like to insert over 1,000 usernames and passwords into the ASP.Identity Users and Memberships table.  Ideally, I would like to encrypt the passwords when they are inserted.  Can this be done with T-SQL or do I have to use some code in C# to loop through a routine that will encrypt the passwords and insert the usernames and possibly other information? An example of this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, So I found a way to bulk insert in AspNet Identity Tables Without Performance Hit.

```
public void CreateBulkIdentityUsers(List<string> userNames)
    {
        using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            var users = context.Users.Where(u => userNames.Contains(u.UserName)).ToList();

            PasswordHasher passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher();

            foreach (var userName in userNames)
            {
                var user = users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser()
                    {
                        UserName = userName,
                        EmailConfirmed = false,
                        PhoneNumberConfirmed = false,
                        TwoFactorEnabled = false,
                        LockoutEnabled = false,
                        PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword("Password@123"),
                        SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower()
                    };

                    context.Users.Add(user);
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

1. getting all users before the loop. so that we can check if that user already exists in the database.
2. initilizing PasswordHasher to hash Password.
3. Finding a User if found then just skip it. if not found then create a new user with some password.

Hope, This helps someone. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to do this in C#. Try this...

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
foreach (var user in users)
{
    var appUser = new ApplicationUser 
    { 
        UserName = user.UserName  // assign other properties here
    };
    await userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, user.Password);
}
```

Comment: I know its 4 years layter... but the "CreateAsync" method does 1 insert at a time. Wasnt the point to do bulk insert i.e. 400 users in one database transaction?